# Why unable to deploy my website on github pages?

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

I have a React website which I am trying to deploy using GIthub pages.
While following the steps to deploy my application Im getting the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.9a1ecd2c.css from Css Minimizer plugin
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
```

Steps I followed:

1)Creating a repo.

2)Linking local and remote repo

3)adding URL to my package.json file.

4)installing gh-pages

5)adding redeploy and deploy script as :

```
 "predeploy":"npm run build",
    "deploy":"gh-pages -d build",
```

6)running npm run deploy

Comment: you have a / where there shouldn't be one, its nothing to do with the repo, the error message says " Error: Unexpected '/'. " find where that / and remove it

Comment: @WillBrobin where do I find that? Should it be in my code files?

Comment: it will be in the code, most probably a special character with a not by the look of it

Comment: @WillBrobin I checked everywhere,my code isn't breaking and nowhere did I find the symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, I'm not sure if you ever got this figured out, but I ran into a similar issue and mine was a bungled comment somewhere in a css file. It doesn't break when you run locally, but when you run it on github-pages it throws that error.

Example:
*My bungled Comment line*/ -> /*Corrected Comment line*/